# Loading multiple custom nested routes in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

I created a long list of custom route files, and I can't figure out the correct way to load them, and they're separated in multiple folders/nested folders in the `Routes` directory as follow :

```
Routes:
    custom_routes:
        auth.php
        general.php
        export.php
        admin:
            customers:
                customer.php
                list.php
            users:
                user.php
                // ...
            invoices:
                user.php
                // ...
            settings:
                user.php
                // ...
        front:
            account:
                settings:
                    setting.php
                    account.php
                    //...
            cart:
                cart.php
                //...
            contact:
                contact.php
                //...
    api.php
    channels.php
    console.php
    web.php
```

If they were just 1 or 2 additional files I would have added them using the  `RouteServiceProvider`, but in this case there is a lot of them and in multiple nesting levels/folders.

How can I do this the right way?

Answer (score 2):

I think you add something like this to your helper class/file.

**Get route files from nested directories:**

```php
function get_route_files($path, $routes) {
    $excludes = ['.', '..', 'channels.php', 'console.php'];
    foreach(scandir($path) as $routeFile) {
        if (in_array($routeFile, $excludes)) {
            continue;
        } else {
            $filePath = $path . '/' . $routeFile;
            if (is_dir($filePath)) {
                $routes = array_merge($routes, get_route_files($filePath, $routes));
            } else {
                    $alias = get_route_file_alias($filePath);
                    $routes[] = ['path' => str_replace('../routes/', '', $filePath), 'alias' => $alias];
            }
        }
    }

    return $routes;
}
```

**Get aliases for your routes:**

```php
function get_route_file_alias($path) {
    $alias = '';
    foreach($keys = explode('/', $path) as $i => $key) {
        if (!in_array($key, ['..', 'routes'])) {
            if ($i <= count($keys) - 2) {
                    $alias .= $key . '.';
            }
        }
    }
    return $alias;
}
```

**Then, map the following routes to your `RouteServiceProvider`:**

```php
protected function mapApiRoutes() {
    $routes = get_route_files('../routes', []);

    foreach($routes as $route) {
        Route::prefix('api')
            // ->middleware($middleware)  -- if there's any
            ->as($route['alias'])
            ->namespace($this->namespace . "\\API")
            ->group($route['path']);
    }
}
```